# High cpu and loading when using systemd socket activation with high concurrency

Tags: systemd

As rhel9 removed xinetd, we started the process of moving to systemd socket activation for short-lived service. But under high concurrency (in fact it's not that high, only about 50 max), host loading and cpu usage becomes high, 3 in loading and about 95% in cpu. It seems that for every socket activated services, systemd creates a cgroup for it and remove it when process ends, causing it consuming cpu a lot. Is there any ways to override this behavior?Create slices for it does not help. Using xinetd does not have this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> systemd creates a cgroup for it and remove it when process ends, causing it consuming cpu a lot. Is there any ways to override this behavior?

No; systemd service tracking is fundamentally cgroup-based.

If building your own xinetd package is not an option, I would suggest porting the service to inherit the *listening* socket instead of the per-client socket, and to have its own accept() loop (perhaps forking for each client to minimize the amount of changes needed). This mode was also supported in (x)inetd as the 'wait' mode; in systemd it's known as 'Accept=no' (uses a non-instanced .service unit).

(Something like `while (fd = accept()) { if (!fork()) handle_client(fd) }` might suffice.)